# Why do I get such a high MSE when I choose a multivariate target?

Tags: linear-regression

I have this dataset:
[image]

Here's how I currently create my data and univariate target:

```
X = data_copy.drop(columns=["Date"]).values
y = data["Date"].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=True)
```

With this model:

```
lin_reg = Pipeline([("MinMaxScaler", MinMaxScaler()),
                   ("LinearRegression", LinearRegression())])
```

I get an MSE of 4.376690269172973e+34.

However, if I do this:

```
y = data_copy.drop(columns=["Date"]).values
X = data["Date"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

I get such a high MSE that is close to six digits! Why? Ideally, I want X to be my date, and y to be my multivariate target, not the other way around. What's the issue here?

Comment: Note that your first MSE is *much* larger than the second (note the `e+34` on the end!)

Comment: I would not recommend using linear regression for time series data.